# Is it really necessary to override the `*_type=` method for ActiveRecord Polymorphic Association with Single Table Inheritance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm refactoring some piece of code that deals with polymorphic `belongs_to` association that can receive a model that implements Single Table Inheritance. The current code follows an advice from `ActiveRecord` documentation [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Polymorphic+Associations), namely that it is best to override `attachable_type=` so that the base class name of the STI model gets stored in the `attachable_type` field:

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :attachable, polymorphic: true

  def attachable_type=(class_name)
     super(class_name.constantize.base_class.to_s)
  end
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  # because we store "Post" in attachable_type now dependent: :destroy will work
  has_many :assets, as: :attachable, dependent: :destroy
end

class GuestPost < Post
end

class MemberPost < Post
end
```

I understand that we want to store that base class so that `ActiveRecord` works as expected. However, when I tested a few scenarios including the scenario in the documentation, it seems that overriding `attachable_type=` is unnecessary. `ActiveRecord` seems to already handle this case and always stores the base model `Post` rather than `GuestPost` or `MemberPost`.

I created a [repo](https://github.com/vaharoni/arpolytest) that implements the models in the documentation and allows you to play with some data and see for yourself. I cannot reproduce the issue that the documentation attempts to circumvent all the way up to `ActiveRecord` version 3.2.22.5 (I haven't tried beyond that).

Does anyone know if there is truly a need to override `attachable_type=`? Is the documentation out of date? Or is it just solving the use case of directly running `Asset.new attachable_type: 'MemberPost', attachable_id: member_post.id` instead of `Asset.new attachable: member_post`?

The reason why this matters to me is that we have 5 models that could be affected by this. Our current code implements overriding 3 of those, and I'm refactoring to DRY it up and potentially introduce it to the additional 2 other models in which we forgot to follow this advice.

Comment: Usually you go with STI *or* polymorphic relationships. Is it unavoidable that you need both?

Comment: Yeah sometimes it's necessary as these do not solve the same issue. For example, an asset might belong to a regular model such as `User` (for the avatar) and an STI model such as `Post` through one of its concrete models `GuestPost` or `MemberPost`. The STI reflects "specialization" of the `Post` model. It does not solve the fact that another model - `Asset` - needs to reflect some relationship with posts as well as with other models in the system (polymorphic relationship).

Answer (score 1):

OK, I believe I better understand the reasoning behind it. This is an issue when the model needs to be created or updated from a form.

In such scenario, `attachable_type` and `attachable_id` are sent to the controller, which typically passes-through this data to the model. Without overriding `attachable_type=` the model will end up having `attachable_type` be one of the child classes `GuestPost` or `MemberPost`.

This in turn causes a range of issues. For example, assets won't be destroyed when the owner of the asset is destroyed even when `dependent: :destroy` is specified on the `has_many` association.

Therefore, if your model is expected to receive data for the polymorphic association field via a form, you should override this method.

I updated the repo to demonstrate this issue.